# Utils to get path from URL

Tags: java, url, path

I need to get the path after the domain name. 
Ex: The url is https://vaadin.com:8080/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authenticating+Vaadin-based+applications/pop_up 
I want to get `/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authenticating+Vaadin-based+applications/pop_up`. 
Is there any Utils class for java to do this quickly?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just use `getPath()` of `URL` class? see here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath%28%29

> Class URL represents a Uniform Resource Locator, a pointer to a
>   "resource" on the World Wide Web. A resource can be something as
>   simple as a file or a directory, or it can be a reference to a more
>   complicated object, such as a query to a database or to a search
>   engine. More information on the types of URLs and their formats can be
>   found at:
>
> ```
> http://www.socs.uts.edu.au/MosaicDocs-old/url-primer.html
> ```
>
> In general, a URL can be broken into several parts. The previous
>   example of a URL indicates that the protocol to use is http (HyperText
>   Transfer Protocol) and that the information resides on a host machine
>   named www.socs.uts.edu.au. The information on that host machine is
>   named /MosaicDocs-old/url-primer.html. The exact meaning of this name
>   on the host machine is both protocol dependent and host dependent. The
>   information normally resides in a file, but it could be generated on
>   the fly. This component of the URL is called the path component.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yan Foto suggested the best way is to use java.net.URL class.

Example:

```
URL url = new URL("https://vaadin.com:8080/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authenticating+Vaadin-based+applications/pop_up");

System.out.print("Path: " + url.getPath());
```

It prints following output :

```
Path: wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authenticating+Vaadin-based+applications/pop_up
```

Comment: +1 It looks like someone down voted this answer. Not sure why. It expands on @Yan Foto 's answer with example code which is helpful.

Comment: this is because if the last part of the url is for example test.html, then it gets included if getPath() is called.